# React drag and drop with responsive grid layout without external libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a drag-and-drop functionality in React with responsive css grid layout (1, 2 or 3 columns) and without external libraries.

The concept would be:
In the Jobs component I have a state variable, containing the id-s of the items to display in an array, which represents their order.
Each item is a Draggable component, sitting in a JobContainer, which then gets gridColumn and GridRow props, calculated based on the index of the item in the order state. When I drag an item to a new position, the order state will be updated.

The Draggable component itself tracks the mouse events and calculates x and y translation values from the origin (where you click on the item), and then the translation values will be applied to the div styles (with transform: translate), so far so good. Based on the translation values and the id of the item, in the Jobs component it will be calculated if the place where the item have been dragged is a valid place for the item to be droppped(if there is another item), and if so, then items will be reordered.

The problem is, that if I drag an item, and it gets to the new place, the item jumps over in the direction it was dragged, so that the cursor is not over it anymore. I think it's because of the rerender of the elements, especially the dragged element, because then the translation may be calculated from it's new position or I don't know. I can not find a way to solve the issue.

If you know a better way to implement drag-and-drop with responsive grid, please let me know, since I don't necessarily need to do it the way I was trying, but unfortunately I haven't find anything, that would work the way I want.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-gauss-qxoftd)

***Draggable.js***

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
  useRef
} from "react";

const POSITION = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const TRANSITION_INTERVAL = 300;

const Draggable = ({ children, onDrag, id }) => {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState(POSITION);
  const [translation, setTranslation] = useState(POSITION);
  const [zIndex, setZIndex] = useState(1);
  const zIndexTimeoutRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
    setOrigin({ x: clientX, y: clientY });
  }, []);

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
      const translation = { x: clientX - origin.x, y: clientY - origin.y };
      setTranslation(translation);
      onDrag({ translation, id });
    },
    [id, onDrag, origin]
  );

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    setIsDragging(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDragging) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

      setTranslation(POSITION);
    }
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [isDragging, handleMouseMove, handleMouseUp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function startTimeOut() {
      zIndexTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setZIndex(1);
      }, TRANSITION_INTERVAL);
    }
    function stopTimeout() {
      clearTimeout(zIndexTimeoutRef.current);
    }

    if (!isDragging && !zIndexTimeoutRef.current) {
      startTimeOut();
      return;
    }
    if (isDragging) {
      stopTimeout();
      zIndexTimeoutRef.current = null;
      setZIndex(2);
      return;
    }
  }, [isDragging]);

  let styles = useMemo(
    () => ({
      cursor: isDragging ? "grabbing" : "grab",
      transform: `translate(${translation.x}px, ${translation.y}px)`,
      transition: isDragging ? "none" : `transform ${TRANSITION_INTERVAL}ms`,
      position: isDragging ? "absolute" : "relative",
      zIndex: zIndex
    }),
    [isDragging, translation, zIndex]
  );

  return (
    <div style={styles} onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Draggable;
```

***Jobs.js***

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "styled-components";

import useCurrentViewPort from "../hooks/useCurrentViewPort";
import { Wrapper, JobContainer } from "../styles/Jobs.styles";
import JobCard from "./JobCard";
import Draggable from "./Draggable";

import { fakeJobs } from "../constants";

const CARD_HEIGHT = 300;

const Jobs = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { width: vw, vmin } = useCurrentViewPort();

  const [order, setOrder] = useState(null);
  const [jobs] = useState(fakeJobs);
  const throttling = useRef(false);

  const columns = useMemo(() => {
    if (vw >= theme.breakpoints.md) return 3;
    if (vw >= theme.breakpoints.sm) return 2;
    return 1;
  }, [theme.breakpoints.md, theme.breakpoints.sm, vw]);
  const gap = useMemo(() => 0.02 * vmin, [vmin]);

  const cardWidth = useMemo(() => {
    const maxWidth = Number(theme.sizing.maxWidth.slice(0, -2));
    const result =
      (Math.min(0.9 * vw, maxWidth) - (columns - 1) * gap) / columns;
    return result;
  }, [columns, gap, theme.sizing.maxWidth, vw]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jobs) {
      const newOrder = jobs.map((job) => job._id);
      setOrder(newOrder);
    }
  }, [jobs]);

  const isValid = useCallback(
    (index, delta) => {
      if (
        delta.x >= -index % columns &&
        delta.y >= -Math.floor(index / columns) &&
        delta.x <=
          Math.min(columns - 1 - (index % columns), jobs.length - 1 - index) &&
        delta.y <= Math.floor((jobs.length - 1 - index) / columns) &&
        (delta.x || delta.y) !== 0
      )
        return true;
      return false;
    },
    [columns, jobs.length]
  );

  const handleDrag = useCallback(
    ({ translation, id: jobId }) => {
      if (throttling.current) {
        return;
      }
      throttling.current = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        throttling.current = false;
        const delta = {
          x: Math.round(translation.x / cardWidth),
          y: Math.round(translation.y / CARD_HEIGHT)
        };
        const jobIndex = order.indexOf(jobId);
        if (!isValid(jobIndex, delta)) return;
        const newOrder = order.filter((id) => id !== jobId);
        const newJobIndex = jobIndex + delta.x + delta.y * columns;
        newOrder.splice(newJobIndex, 0, jobId);
        setOrder(newOrder);
      }, 50);
    },
    [cardWidth, columns, isValid, order]
  );

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <>
        <div id="jobs-container">
          {jobs.map((job) => {
            const index = order?.indexOf(job._id);
            const gridColumn = 1 + (index % columns);
            const gridRow = Math.floor(index / columns) + 1;
            return (
              <JobContainer
                key={job._id}
                id={job._id}
                cardHeight={CARD_HEIGHT}
                gridPosition={{ gridColumn, gridRow }}
              >
                <Draggable onDrag={handleDrag} id={job._id}>
                  <JobCard {...job} cardHeight={CARD_HEIGHT} />
                </Draggable>
              </JobContainer>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Jobs;
```